# Svelte transitions create empty style tags in the markup

Tags: javascript, svelte

At the moment there's a bug in svelte where any svelte/transition will create a new style in the document head when it fires. Needless to say this stacks up quickly when transitions are present all over a codebase. I was wondering if anyone found a way to either prevent this from happening or if the quick and dirty fix I made to my own site will break anything.

On the top level I `setInterval()` that gets all the empty styles in `<head>` and removes them.
I'm unsure if the synchronous nature of JS makes this safe or not, or if when the timing is just right, it breaks.

Thanks

Comment: Has this been reported in the Svelte repository?

Comment: Hello again H.B. :)
Yes it has, a few times starting early 2021 as far as I've found.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is safe or not depends on whether the Svelte code that interacts with the style is asynchronous or not. If your code is synchronous it will run uninterrupted, however, the Svelte code might interact with the style tag in a way that causes problems if it is split up into multiple interactions.

Chances of this are low, even if the code is asynchronous because if you remove the style tag and the creating code still has a reference to it, it may not matter whether the style tag has been removed from the document or not as long there is no reliance on the hierarchy (like parent nodes). I doubt that there is much if any asynchronous interaction with the style but to be sure, you would have to check the Svelte source code responsible.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Unfortunately I've only started using svelte recently and so it would take me a lot of time to familiarize with svelte's internals to confirm it.
Looks like my mention of the issue on the git tracker got a PR moving, yay!
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/7260

Comment: Good to see that this should be resolved soon.

Comment: Indeed, I did find out if it breaks something and it does. When the transition is long enough and the node removal happens during, it interrupts the transition and lags (and some harder to describe visual effects). So I'll just sit tight until the PR is merged.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue recently.
Until Svelte core fixes this I added this code:

```
const remove_empty_styles  = () => {
    var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getElementsByTagName('style');
    Array.from(styles).forEach(v=>{
        if (v.innerText === '')
        {
            v.parentNode.removeChild(v);
        }
    })
}
setInterval(remove_empty_styles, 10000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Dolby In the last comment to HB I mentioned that doing this does break transitions at least visually. So it's probably best to avoid doing this. That said, the fix was added to core since then and you can simply update your project to latest version :)